# Thermal Conduction with multilayered system

Tags: thermodynamics

Sorry this question probably has a really simple answer but I have been looking and I can't figure out how to solve this problem. I know that the equation for power loss through conduction is $\frac{(k)(A)(\Delta T)}{l}$ (where $k$ is conductivity, $A$ is the cross-sectional area, $l$ is the width of the panel and $\Delta T$ is the change in the temperature. However, how do I do this for a two-layered system in which each material has a different thickness and conductivity? I know that the problem is trivial if I know the temperature of the interface but I have no idea how to figure out what that would be.

Any help is appreciated and thank you in advance!

Comment: You need to apply energy conservation. The heat flowing trough the first interface is the same as that trough the second, third etc.. Layers which have different conductivity will therefor have different temperature drops across them. The total temperature drop is then simply the sum of that of all individual layers.

Comment: So I write the equations for both individual systems and set the power outputs equal to each other and then solve for the temperature of the interface? (At which point it becomes trivial to solve the whole thing)

Comment: That should do it.

Comment: In practice, one way to attack these multi-layer problems is by an [analogy between heat transfer and electricity](http://www.egr.msu.edu/~raguin/ME812/FinalProjects/Lindberg_FinalProject.htm). This is a great way to handle pretty complex situations with conduction, convection and (sometimes)radiation.